# como puedo comparar dos campos en ajax y mostrar resultado?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ajax

¿Cómo puedo chequear el nombre y el día de la semana en AJAX?
En este ejemplo de código de PHP y AJAX tengo dos campos, uno de ellos se llama nombre y el otro diasemana.

Este código me busca solamente por el campo nombre y lo que necesito es que también me busque la coincidencia del campo diasemana. Por ejemplo, quiero que me busque coincidencia si el nombre es JUAN PEREZ y diasemana es LUNES. Entonces que me salga una alerta sobre que encontró esa coincidencia.

Este es mi código:

Index.php:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
         <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
         <title>Chequear nombre y diasemana</title>
         <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"> 
        </script>
       <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function()
        {    
        $("#nombre").keyup(function()
         {  
        var nombre = $(this).val(); 
         if(nombre.length > 3)
       {  
       $("#result").html('chequeando...');
       $.ajax({
       type : 'POST',
       url  : 'chequearnombre.php',
       data : $(this).serialize(),
       success : function(data) {
      $("#result").html(data);
     }
     });
     return false;
       }
     else
        {
     $("#result").html('');
       }
       });
      });
     </script>
     </head>
      <body>
      <form id="reg-form" action="" method="post" autocomplete="off">
      <fieldset>
        <div>
        <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" />
        <span id="result"></span>
        </div>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
        </body>
         </html>
```

chequearnombre.php:

```
               <?php
                $host="localhost";
                $user="root";
                $pass="";
                $dbname="sistema";
                $dbcon = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname}",$user,$pass);
                    if($_POST) 
                           {
                  $nombre = strip_tags($_POST['nombre']);
                   $stmt=$dbcon->prepare("SELECT nombre FROM medicos WHERE 
                   nombre=:nombre");
                   $stmt->execute(array(':nombre'=>$nombre));
                    $count=$stmt->rowCount();
                         if($count>0)
                     {
                      echo "<span style='color:brown;'>El nombre y dia de la semana ya 
                     existe en la base de datos !!!</span>";
                         }
                        else
                         {
                       echo "<span style='color:green;'>No existe !</span>";
                       }
                         }
                         ?>
```

¿Alguien me podría ayudar?

Comment: Tu pregunta no es clara. ¿Cuál es la columna en la que se debe verificar el día de la semana?

Comment: los dos campos a verificar serían:  campo 1 (nombre) campo 2 (diasemana)

Comment: ¿De qué tipo es `diasemana` en la tabla, de tipo `date`, de tipo `datetime` o de otro tipo?

Comment: es de tipo varchar(30) al igual que nombre

Comment: Debiste declararla `date` o `datetime` de lo contrario tendrás que convertirla y luego verificar si es lunes. ¿En qué formato se guardan las fechas actualmente?

Comment: en dd/mm/yyyy 26/12/2022